# Popping up facebook login dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, facebook-login, facebook-iframe

I am writing a library to get short lived tokens from facebook.I am simply making an iframe and opening the dialog inside. If user is signed in before theres no problem but if user will be prompted first time facebook blocks iframe my code is below how can i solve this problem .

```
function Facebook (params){
    this.url="https://facebook.com/dialog/oauth"+params;
    this.Get=function(){
        var css="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;\
        transform:translate(-50%,-50%);width:500px;height:300px;z-index:9999",
        frame=document.createElement("iframe"),
        url=this.url;
        frame.setAttribute("style",css);
        return {
            pop:function(){
                document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(frame);
                alert(url);
                frame.setAttribute("src",url);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can not show the Facebook login dialog in any kind of (i)frames, for security reasons.

Comment: @CBroe and if i try window.open most browsers are blocking that what to do about this any idea ?

Comment: Use a normal link with `target="_blank"` instead? (Or as fall back, by checking the return value of a `window.open` call first, and if that signals success, cancel the click event on the link.)

Comment: i tried _blank with link anyway chrome blocks it @CBroe

Comment: Why not just use the [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript)? It does pretty much what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by opening popup if the popup from a trusted event such as click browsers doesnt block it while trying from console anyway they will block